# xslt transform an xsd validated xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a very strange effect when adding the `schemaLocation` to my xml-file.

**Problem**:

> When adding the `xsi:schemaLocation="Projekt.xsd"` to the root element of my xml file, the xslt transformation does not work anymore. When I don't specify the xsd-File, the transformation works and the data gets displayed but **as soon as I add the xsd-File, no data are getting displayed anymore.**

- What am I missing, so that the data still get displayed and transformed correctly after adding the xsd-File to the schemaLocation?

**Info:** ***All files are in the same folder***

---

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Projekt.xsl"?>
<school xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="Projekt.xsd">
    <personen>
        <person id="1">
            <name>A</name>
            <kuerzel>a</kuerzel>
            <email>a@a.ch</email>
        </person>
        <person id="2">
            <name>B</name>
            <kuerzel>b</kuerzel>
            <email>b@b.ch</email>
        </person>
        <person id="3">
            <name>C</name>
            <kuerzel>C</kuerzel>
            <email>c@c.ch</email>
        </person>
    </personen>
</school>
```

## XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="school">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="personen" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="person">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>        
                                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="kuerzel" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>

        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

## XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>School</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Kürzel</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Email</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Image</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="school/personen/person">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="kuerzel"/></td>
        <td><a href="mailto:{email}"><xsl:value-of select="email" /></a></td>
        <td><img src="http://tempUri.com/{kuerzel}.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong in my files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `schemaLocation` does not matter but your input sample has the default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"` on the root element which puts all elements in that namespace. Your XSLT however uses paths like `school/personen/person` which (in XSLT/XPath 1.0) select elements in no namespace. Either move to an XSLT 2.0 processor where you can then define `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3schools.com"` on your stylesheet or, if you want to solve it with XSLT 1.0, declare `xmlns:df="http://www.w3schools.com"` in your stylesheet and adapt your paths to use that prefix as in `df:school/df:personen/df:person` and `df:name` and so on.